# Uploading Image in Asp.net mvc Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, file-upload, httppostedfilebase

I have a Upload form and I want to pass my information such as an Image and some other field but I don't know how can I upload Image ..

This is  My model class

```html
public partial class NewProductCategory
    {   
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        public string ProductPrice { get; set; }
        public string ProductImage { get; set; }
        public string ProductQuantity { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> ProductStatus { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CategoryId { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase user_image_data { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    }
```

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(NewProductCategory productcategory, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ProductCategory newproductCategory = new ProductCategory();
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/files"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                file.SaveAs(path);
                newproductCategory.ProductDescription = productcategory.ProductDescription;
                newproductCategory.ProductQuantity = productcategory.ProductQuantity;
                newproductCategory.ProductStatus = productcategory.ProductStatus;

                newproductCategory.CategoryId = productcategory.CategoryId;

                db.ProductCategories.Add(newproductCategory);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId", "Name", productcategory.CategoryId);
            return View(productcategory);
        }
```

And this is My View Code

```html
@model MvcApplication1.Models.NewProductCategory
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>ProductCategory</legend>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Temp", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

        {
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductDescription)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductDescription)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductDescription)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductPrice)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductPrice)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductPrice)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user_image_data)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
               @Html.Label("Upload your image")
            </div>


            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.user_image_data, new { Type = "File" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user_image_data)
            </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductQuantity)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductQuantity)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductQuantity)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductStatus)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductStatus)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductStatus)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, "Category")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
        }
    </fieldset>
}
```

please help me in controller i am getting Null value for File upload

Comment: Because you binding to a property named `user_image_data` (not `file`) but you have not shown your model so we do not know what that is - it should be typeof `HttpPostedFileBase`. If you want to bind to a parameter named `file` then name the input `file`

Comment: Ya i had done using HttpPostedFileBase, but i have an issue that 
@model MvcApplication1.Models.NewProductCategory without this it can run but with another input field it getting error 
and ok i will edit and add my model class too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update Ansawer**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.NewProductCategory
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

   @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Temp", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

    {    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>ProductCategory</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductDescription)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductDescription)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductDescription)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductPrice)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductPrice)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductPrice)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user_image_data)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.user_image_data, new { Type = "File" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user_image_data)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Upload your image")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.TextBox("file",null,htmlAttributes: new { Type = "file" })
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductQuantity)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductQuantity)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductQuantity)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductStatus)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductStatus)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductStatus)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, "Category")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>  
      </fieldset>
    }
```

Comment: I have done above changes , still getting null value in httpHttpPostedFileBase file , now what other option , 

i simply created a demo without the model class it work fine , but while add and passing with (NewProductCategory productcategory, HttpPostedFileBase file) this class getting null value